# Обернуть все li в ul если они дочерние

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть меню сайта

```
<ul>
  <li>Меню1</li>
  <li>Меню2</li>
  <li>Меню3
    <li>ДочМеню3</li>
    <li>ДочМеню3</li>
    <li>ДочМеню3</li>
  </li>     
</ul>
```

Если в Меню3 будут еще дочерние элементы, то их обернуть в `<ul class="sub"></ul>`

```
 <ul>
  <li>Меню1</li>
  <li>Меню2</li>
  <li>Меню3
    <ul class="sub">
     <li>ДочМеню3</li>
     <li>ДочМеню3</li>
     <li>ДочМеню3</li>
    <ul>
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Как правильно написать на js? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Чтоооо? Поправьте разметку, не сразу понятен вопрос, ul в ul лежать не может. А вот ul>li>ul может, вы наверное имеет ввиду если в li будут другие li, то их уже заключить в отдельный список.

Comment: Да, не правильно написал

Comment: Нужно решение именно на чистом JS?

Comment: Вообще да, но можете предложить другой вариант если не сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что браузер как только натыкается на новый открытый `<li>`, когда предыдущий еще не закрыт - автоматически закрывает его, потом только идет дальше. Поэтому изначально не может быть такой ситуации, чтобы li были внутри других... поэтому можно заранее записать их в виде div, а подменить на li только после добавления ul.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('ul');

var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

for( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ){
  var div = li[i].querySelector('div');
  if( div ){ //Если внутри очередного li есть div...

    var x = li[i]; 
    // здесь методы вставки HTML не прокатят, потому что браузер автоматически
    // дописывает теги и мешает. Поэтому только регулярки.
    
    x.outerHTML = x.outerHTML.replace(/<div>/, '<ul class="sub"><div>')
                             .replace(/<\/li>/, '</ul></li>')
                             .replace(/(<|<\/)div>/g,"$1li>"); 
    // $1 указывает на то, что в скобках, внутри выражения
    
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li>Меню1</li>
  <li>Меню2</li>
  <li>Меню3
    <div>ДочМеню3</div>
    <div>ДочМеню3</div>
    <div>ДочМеню3</div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

P.s. и я всё равно не представил, где в реальной жизни можно наткнуться на такую задачу.

Comment: Спасибо, испытаем.